# Creating New Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis, reshape

I have data in this format in R

```
customer_key    item_key    units
2669699            16865    1.00
2669699            16866    1.00
2669699            46963    2.00
2685256            55271    1.00
2685256            43458    1.00
2685256            54977    1.00
2685256             2533    1.00
2685256            55011    1.00
2685256            44785    2.00
```

but I want to get the unique head_key as column and I want my the other variables name be the unique values in item_key and their value would be the units like this

```
customer_key       '16865'   '16866'  '46963'  '55271'   '43458'   '54977'    '2533'
    2669699          1.00     1.00     1.00     0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00 
    2685256          0.00     0.00     0.00     1.00      1.00      1.00       2.00
```

Please help me transform my data for cluster analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
library(tidyr)

spread(mydf,item_key, units, fill = 0)

#  customer_key 2533 16865 16866 43458 44785 46963 54977 55011 55271
#1      2669699    0     1     1     0     0     2     0     0     0
#2      2685256    1     0     0     1     2     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I think pipes are just unnecessary here, just `spread(df, item_key, units, fill = 0)` would be sufficient. It is also interesting that you didn't need to specify `customer_key`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that. You are right. I revised my answer. I still think in `dacst` ways and get a bit confused with the syntax. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's just a simple `dcast` task. Assuming `df` is your data set

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, customer_key ~ item_key , value.var = "units", fill = 0)
#   customer_key 2533 16865 16866 43458 44785 46963 54977 55011 55271
# 1      2669699    0     1     1     0     0     2     0     0     0
# 2      2685256    1     0     0     1     2     0     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the packages have been covered (+1 to you all), here are a couple of base solutions to join the party:

`xtabs`:

```
xtabs(units ~ customer_key + item_key, df)
#             item_key
# customer_key 2533 16865 16866 43458 44785 46963 54977 55011 55271
#      2669699    0     1     1     0     0     2     0     0     0
#      2685256    1     0     0     1     2     0     1     1     1
```

`reshape`

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "customer_key", timevar = "item_key")
#   customer_key units.16865 units.16866 units.46963 units.55271
# 1      2669699           1           1           2          NA
# 4      2685256          NA          NA          NA           1
#   units.43458 units.54977 units.2533 units.55011 units.44785
# 1          NA          NA         NA          NA          NA
# 4           1           1          1           1           2
```

Comment: (+1) The good old `xtabs`. I always forget about him. `reshape` was always an awkward function

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% arrange(item_key) %>% spread(item_key, units, fill=0)
df2
#   customer_key 2533 16865 16866 43458 44785 46963 54977 55011 55271
# 1      2669699    0     1     1     0     0     2     0     0     0
# 2      2685256    1     0     0     1     2     0     1     1     1
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(customer_key = c(2669699L, 2669699L, 2669699L, 
2685256L, 2685256L, 2685256L, 2685256L, 2685256L, 2685256L), 
    item_key = c(16865L, 16866L, 46963L, 55271L, 43458L, 54977L, 
    2533L, 55011L, 44785L), units = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2)), .Names = c("customer_key", "item_key", "units"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```